# mysql find rows with most "true" in columns based on input

Tags: mysql

I have a table as:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|id |has_item_1|has_item_2|has_item_3|has_item_4             |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 54| true      |false        |false        |true
| 63| false     |false        |true         |true
| 12| true      |true         |true         |true
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the user can specify which items s/he wants to be exist, the result should be ordered by the most items matched.
E.g for the input `has_item_1, has_item_2` it should return the table in the order `12 54 63` 
and for the query `has_item_3, has_item_4` it should return the table in the order `12, 63, 54`
running the query 
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE has_item_1 = true OR has_item_2 = true` doesn't order the results as to "most hits".
Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, for more information on FIELD, here some documentation : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_field.asp

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE has_item_1 = 'True'
    OR has_item_2 = 'True'
ORDER BY FIELD(has_item1, 'True', 'False'), FIELD(has_item2, 'True', 'False')
```

For the second query, if 2 rows have the same 'True' value, to chose between 12 and 63 you can add an order by id :

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE has_item_3 = 'True'
    OR has_item_4 = 'True'
ORDER BY FIELD(has_item3, 'True', 'False'), FIELD(has_item4, 'True', 'False'), id
```

Edit : you can even simplify the above query as if it's not a value in FIELD the return value will be 0.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE has_item_3 = 'True'
    OR has_item_4 = 'True'
ORDER BY FIELD(has_item3, 'True') DESC, FIELD(has_item4, 'True') DESC, id
```